# What is the default value of Value[]?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jstl

What is the default value of `Value[]`, why because, I need the default value to write test cases.

`property.getValues` will return `Value[]`, but just want to see what exactly the default value of  `Value[]`

Thanks

Comment: from where are you getting this so called, `property.getValues`?

Comment: no I am absoluly sure it is 42...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any Java array, object fields of array type `Value[]` default to `null`, regardless of the exact type of `Value`:

```
public class Demo {
    private int[] intArray;
    private String[] strArray;
    private MyClass[] myArray;
}
```

In the example above, `intArray`, `strArray`, and `myArray` will be `null` until you assign them a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Anything that holds an object is initialized to null. 
int/short/byte 0.
float/double 0.0
booleans false.
```

When you create an array with new and an array size, all entries are zeroed. 
In this case the answer is null.  You need to explicitly initialize any local variables.